# Why is location.search not blank here?

Tags: javascript

The page's current URL is

[image]

However, when I try checking for `location.search`'s value, it shows up as this :

[image]

The URL runs through a reverse proxy with `mod_rewrite`'s in it, and it is identical to what is in the search and pathname.

What does `location.search` and `location.pathname` really do, and where do the values come from?

Comment: I just tried going to that URL, and `location.search` gives an empty string...but it's currently giving a 500 error, so maybe you're working on it and that's why...

Comment: There must be some confusion, because JS should be seeing the URL in the address bar...see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4122799/560114.

Comment: Sorry, the folder name has been changed and it's now `/ocd-support-group`. However, it isn't showing the same problems anymore. I notice this happens randomly, about 1/3 of the time. I will continue to monitor the URLs and location variables and see if it happens again.